# NModbus4 startAddress is more than ushort can handle

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus, plc

I'm programming a PLC with a C# application with NModbus4. (RS232)
I can read data with `master.ReadCoils(device, 8192, 1)`.

Now i've an address like 149153. This is to long for a ushort so i can't pass it as a parameter to ReadCoils.

How can i do this?

Comment: Modbus addresses are 16-bit unsigned integers. There's no address like 149153. Check the PLC's user manual, that address is a vendor specific one, they must provide details on how to map it to Modbus standard ones.

Comment: I used the Click programming software to get the addresses. In the Address picker I can tick on `Display MODBUS` address. Then choose between 984 or HEX addressing. I chose the 984 addressing and something like CTD1. Then the MODBUS address is: `449153 (03,06,16)`. Do you have a way to detect the right ones?

Comment: Maybe the first digit is telling you the data type. Try reading the holding register with address 49153. Or coil number 49153. Does the returned data makes sense?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You where right with some of the addresses. I've just read all the possible addresses and checked in which ranges which addresses where! Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PLC is using a very common address notation for Modbus (although not standard), where the first digit defines the register's data type:

- 0 (coils)
- 1 (discrete inputs)
- 3 (input registers)
- 4 (holding registers)

So, data at address 149153 is actually the discrete input at address 49153.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information! I'm new to PLC programming and this made it a lot clearer!

Comment: Can you also take a look to another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989040/nmodbus4-read-txt-from-plc